# Datatable 1.10.x delete doesn't work while the user is applying a filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using socket.io to update/delete rows with Datatable 1.10.x, but if the socket sends some info that I use to delete a row while the user is applying a filter, the delete doesn't work.

```
var row = document.getElementById('con_'+idtaxi);
$('#tblconectados').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`$()`](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#$) API method to access elements not available in DOM as shown below.

```
$('#tblconectados').dataTable().fnDeleteRow(
   $('#tblconectados').$('#con_'+idtaxi).get(0)
);
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mdq4kyq/) for code and demonstration.